# When I try to minimize windows, they close?

Tags: unity, window-buttons

When I try to minimize windows they close!

Comment: What do you do to try to minimize windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I accidentally removed the Window's List application from the Desktop, once I put it back everything returned to normal!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the window border theme. It could be that the images don't match with the buttons or aren't placed properly.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: @Mitch It could be construed to be an answer under some circumstances.